# Creating Cordova App through PHP in MAC OS

Tags: php, python, bash, macos, cordova

I am trying to make the cordova app using PHP and i am using MAC OS . The problem is that when i try to run the command through php/bash script or through Python i get this error message .

```
 at require (internal/module.js:20:19)Array ( [0] => path.js:7 [1] => 
 throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + 
 inspect(path)); [2] => ^ [3] => [4] => TypeError: Path must be a
 string. Received undefined [5] => at assertPath (path.js:7:11) [6] 
 => at Object.join (path.js:1211:7) [7] => at Object. (/usr/local
 /lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova
/util.js:38:31) [8] => at Module._compile (module.js:571:32) [9] => 
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10) [10] => at 
Module.load (module.js:488:32) [11] => at tryModuleLoad 
(module.js:447:12) [12] => at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3) 
[13] => at Module.require (module.js:498:17) [14] => at require
(internal/module.js:20:19) )
```

Where as if i run the script from bash or python the same script run smoothly but with PHP Exec function it keep giving me this error .

I am running these commands

```
putenv('PATH='. getenv('PATH') .':/usr/local/bin');
print_r(exec("cordova create ppp 2>&1",$output,$return_val));
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Looks like you're requiring a JavaScript file into your PHP page. Also, you should know that `require` is not a function.

Comment: hi i am just executing cordova command . Cordova itself has a javascript files but i am not adding any javascript file